# How to create a file format container?

Tags: video, file-format

I'm working with HTML5 video, revealjs, and quilljs to create a rich video experience. As a video presenter is talking the user can toggle between the video, the presenter's revealjs slides, and quilljs which arbitrary text, all within the video frame. Each video is associated with a one quilljs and one revealjs entry.

I was trying to rack my brain how to package a video, slides and quilljs text into one file format container that can be downloaded as a single file with extension `.xyz` for example, and reuploaded later for playback (Kind of like an MP4 file is really just a container with video, audio and subtitles).

I've spent a few hours researching how to create a container with multiple files but to no avail. I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The MP4 container itself supports three tracks types commonly:

- Video
- Audio
- subtitles

It may be that the subtitles track meets some of your requirements - e.g. you can display the subtitle in a separate view if you want.

More recently, TTML (Timed Text Markup Language) tracks are supported which include the ability to add graphics as well as text to videos.

You can see some info on adding TTML to MP4 (and MPEG DASH) here:

- https://github.com/rbouqueau/TTML_in_MP4_DASH_statement

There is also the ability to add private tracks to MP4 files, although this not common.

Comment: This is interesting. I will definitely look into this! Thank you.